# how to run any query on DataSet?

Tags: c#

i have dataset that contain data.

i need to run any query on this DataSet.

thank's in advance

Comment: Aew  you using Typed Datasets ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the [DataTable.Select method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx). Alternatively, you can take a look at [LINQ to Dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx).

Comment: Ugh, why go for the obvious answer (Select) when you could pile on more obscure, harder to use and altogether more cooool linq?

Answer (score 1):

[Linq to DataSet?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataTable.Select if you need output from one table only.  If the query criteria and primary key are the same, then DataTable.Rows.Find will work much faster

If you need a join between different tables in DataSet, then Linq to dataset will be the answer