# how to run query on dataset?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `DataSet` named `dsView` that contains data. Here is the code i use to read the XML:

```
dsView = new DataSet();
dsView.ReadXml(@"\c:MyXml.xml");
```

The data has a table named `MEN` with fields `Fname` and `Lname`.  How do I run a query on this `dsView`? (for example: `select * from MEN where Fname = 'zz'`)

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939511/how-to-run-any-query-on-dataset

Comment: should be merged with that question since this one contains better answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot run complete SQL statements on a `DataSet` - but the `DataTable` inside your `DataSet` does have a method called `Select(string)` which selects an array of `DataRow` object that match a certain criteria.

Check out the [MSDN docs on DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx)

You would probably have to do something like (untested):

```
DataTable tblMEN = dsView.Tables["MEN"];
DataRow[] results = tblMen.Select("Fname = 'zz'");
```

Comment: @Gali: do a foreach over the array of `DataRow` - that's just standard ADO.NET ....

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can run a SQL query on a `DataSet`, since it doesn't have a query engine. But you could try [LINQ to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx).

Also, if you are only interested in the data (and not the databinding properties of the `DataSet`), I suggest you use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to query the document.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK You can only run a Sql Like query on a **DataTable** with the [Select method.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx)

You would use [this overload of DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) here to do something like this:

```
DataRow[] foundRows = dsView.Table[0].Select("Fname = `zz`");
```

`dsView.Table[0]` should point to the table of *MEN* and should have a column *Fname*

The expressions valid are the same as DataColumn expressions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
dsView.Table[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "Fname = 'zz'";
// now default view contains the filtered rows
//ds.Table[0].DefaultView
```

More about [DefaultVeiw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview.aspx) on msdn

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that I used to make a menu.

```
Dim dstpage As DataSet
dstpage = businessService.GetData()
Dim userTable As DataTable
userTable = dstpage.Tables(0)
If userTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
   Dim results As DataRow()
   results = userTable.Select("PAGE_GROUP_NAME='People'")
   For i As Integer = 0 To results.Count - 1
       FilePath = userTable.Rows(i)("FILE_PATH").ToString()
       PageName = userTable.Rows(i)("PAGE_NAME").ToString()
   Next
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create a table of five different people.
    // ... Store their size and sex.
    DataTable table = new DataTable("Players");
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Size", typeof(int)));
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Sex", typeof(char)));

    table.Rows.Add(100, 'f');
    table.Rows.Add(235, 'f');
    table.Rows.Add(250, 'm');
    table.Rows.Add(310, 'm');
    table.Rows.Add(150, 'm');

    // Search for people above a certain size.
    // ... Require certain sex.
    DataRow[] result = table.Select("Size >= 230 AND Sex = 'm'");
    foreach (DataRow row in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", row[0], row[1]);
    }
```

you can use this code.i hope it's help you.