# Query a datatable where text contains

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, oledb

Building on this question: [how to run query on dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726636/how-to-run-query-on-dataset)

I'm trying to query a datatable from my dataset where the text contains a string, similar to the `String.Contains` method or the sql LIKE operator.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable tbl = globals.UserDataSet.Tables[0];
        DataRow[] tempDataRows = tbl.Select("USER_ID Like " + textBox1.Text + " OR THE_NAME Like " + textBox1.Text);
    }
```

This gives a System.Data.SyntaxError error.

Is it possible to query a datatable for text containing a substring?  Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: you could always use LINQ

Comment: @Kevin I like that idea, can you please refer me to some documentation for using LINQ to search within a datatable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Couple of things:

- First you need to enclose your values in single quote. (that is there in the linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726636/how-to-run-query-on-dataset))
- Second, if you are trying to compare for `Contains` then your values should have `%` *(Just like SQL)*

so your statement should be:

```
DataRow[] tempDataRows = tbl.Select("USER_ID Like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' OR THE_NAME Like '%" + textBox1.Text +"%');
```

You can also use [LINQ to DataSet/DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to filter your results like:

```
var query = tbl.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<string>("USER_ID").Contains(textBox1.Text) &&
                r.Field<string>("THE_NAME").Contains(textBox1.Text));
```

Comment: I just changed a LINQ query on a list of objects to a datatable `.select` as above and picked up a ton of speed

Answer (score 5):

You need to add single quotes around your strings:

```
DataRow[] tempDataRows = tbl.Select("USER_ID Like '" + textBox1.Text + "' OR THE_NAME Like '" + textBox1.Text + "'");
```

Comment: Also the percentage when using Like '%'

Comment: Oops, thank you my mistake.  The "Like" operator doesn't seem to be working though, e.g., typing part of a known USER_ID from the list doesn't return any rows unless I type the whole thing.  I'll modify my question to reflect this.

Comment: Beat me to it @AGhazal

Comment: @AGhazal I assumed (apparently wrongly) that the operators were included in the text value.

Answer (score 1):

You need single quotes and % around string values. It's throwing a syntax error because the constructed query has the raw strings from the inputs, as in "WHERE THE_NAME Like John". Try this:

```
tbl.Select("USER_ID Like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' OR THE_NAME Like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'");
```